# Order columns of a pandas dataframe according to the values in a row

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

How do I order columns according to the values of the last row? In the example below, my final dataframe should have columns in the following order: 'ddd' 'aaa' 'ppp' 'fff'.

```
>>> df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['ddd', 'fff', 'aaa', 'ppp'])
>>> df
        ddd       fff       aaa       ppp
0 -0.177438  0.102561 -1.318710  1.321252
1  0.980348  0.786721  0.374506 -1.411019
2  0.405112  0.514216  1.761983 -0.529482
3  1.659710 -1.017048 -0.737615 -0.388145
4 -0.472223  1.407655 -0.129119 -0.912974
5  1.221324 -0.656599  0.563152 -0.900710
6 -1.816420 -2.898094 -0.232047 -0.648904
7  2.793261  0.568760 -0.850100  0.654704
8 -2.180891  2.054178 -1.050897 -1.461458
9 -1.123756  1.245987 -0.239863  0.359759
```

Answer (score 34):

[updated to simplify]

tl;dr:

```
In [29]: new_columns = df.columns[df.ix[df.last_valid_index()].argsort()]

In [30]: df[new_columns]
Out[30]: 
        aaa       ppp       fff       ddd
0  0.328281  0.375458  1.188905  0.503059
1  0.305457  0.186163  0.077681 -0.543215
2  0.684265  0.681724  0.210636 -0.532685
3 -1.134292  1.832272  0.067946  0.250131
4 -0.834393  0.010211  0.649963 -0.551448
5 -1.032405 -0.749949  0.442398  1.274599
```

---

Some explanation follows.  First, build the `DataFrame`:

```
In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), columns=['ddd', 'fff', 'aaa', 'ppp'])

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
        ddd       fff       aaa       ppp
0  0.503059  1.188905  0.328281  0.375458
1 -0.543215  0.077681  0.305457  0.186163
2 -0.532685  0.210636  0.684265  0.681724
3  0.250131  0.067946 -1.134292  1.832272
4 -0.551448  0.649963 -0.834393  0.010211
5  1.274599  0.442398 -1.032405 -0.749949
```

Get the last row:

```
In [26]: last_row = df.ix[df.last_valid_index()]
```

Get the indices that would sort it:

```
In [27]: last_row.argsort()
Out[27]: 
ddd    2
fff    3
aaa    1
ppp    0
Name: 5, Dtype: int32
```

Use this to index `df`:

```
In [28]: df[last_row.argsort()]
Out[28]: 
        aaa       ppp       fff       ddd
0  0.328281  0.375458  1.188905  0.503059
1  0.305457  0.186163  0.077681 -0.543215
2  0.684265  0.681724  0.210636 -0.532685
3 -1.134292  1.832272  0.067946  0.250131
4 -0.834393  0.010211  0.649963 -0.551448
5 -1.032405 -0.749949  0.442398  1.274599
```

Profit!

Comment: .ix was depracated.  Just replace the .ix in the first example above with .loc

Answer (score 32):

The [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) method does this directly when given `axis=1` argument.

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(df.last_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

---

So, it is no longer necessary to transpose the dataframe to sort by a row. Also, the `sort` method is now  deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use transpose and the sort method (which works on columns):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['ddd', 'fff', 'aaa', 'ppp'])
last_row_name = df.index[-1]
sorted_df = df.T.sort(columns=last_row_name).T
```

You might suffer a performance hit but it is quick and easy.

Answer (score -1):

```
df=df[df.iloc[-1,:].sort_values().index]
```

This works

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: @WhatsThePoint : +1 from my side. Husimu: Please provide your answer with clear descriptions. Don't write the code, give the explanation about the code which you have shared, so that others can also understand and it will be helpful. I request you to read the FAQ Section in-order to use Stack Overflow in an effective manner.